# Cross Stream Data changes - EDW

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, data-warehouse

I got a scenario where Data Stream B is dependent on Data Stream A.  Whenever there is change in Data Stream A it is required re-process the Stream B.  So a common process is required to identify the changes across datastreams and trigger the re-processing tasks.
Is there a good way to do this besides triggers.

Comment: What do you mean by a "data stream"? How exactly are you loading data into your database? And what does it mean when a stream "changes"?

Comment: Data Stream is set of data files related to particular subject area.
Load is through ETL process.  Both Data Streams are load separately.  But when Stream B is loaded lookup is done on Stream A to do some validations.  In case at later stage if there is any modifications to existing Data Stream A (by subsequent load) there should be some sort of trigger to catch changes in stream A and reprocess stream B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather unclear and I think any answer depends very heavily on what your data looks like, how you load it, how you can identify changes, if you need to show multiple versions of one fact or dimension value to users etc.

Here is a short description of how we handle it, it may or may not help you:

1. We load raw data incrementally daily, i.e. we load all data generated in the last 24 hours in the source system (I'm glossing over timing issues, but they aren't important here)
2. We insert the raw data into a loading table; that table already contains all data that we have previously loaded from the same source
3. If rows are completely new (i.e. the PK value in the raw data is new) they are processed normally
4. If we find a row where we already have the PK in the table, we know it is an updated version of data that we've already processed
5. Where we find updated data, we flag it for special processing and re-generate any data depending on it (this is all done in stored procedures)

I think you're asking how to do step 5, but it depends on the data that changes and what your users expect to happen. For example, if one item in an order changes, we re-process the entire order to ensure that the order-level values are correct. If a customer address changes, we have to re-assign him to a new sales region.

There is no generic way to identify data changes and process them, because everyone's data and requirements are different and everyone has a different toolset and different constraints and so on.

If you can make your question more specific then maybe you'll get a better answer, e.g. if you already have a working solution based on triggers then why do you want to change? What problem are you having that is making you look for an alternative?